# Выбрать только уникальные массивы (и с большей длинной) из многомерного массива

Tags: php, массивы

Пример массива:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'alias' => 'test',
        'title' => 'stack',
        'content' => 'overflow',
        'year' => 2019,
        'test' => null
    ),

    1 => array(
        'alias' => null,
        'title' => 'stack',
        'content' => 'overflow',
        'year' => null,
        'test' => null
    ),

    2 => array(
        'alias' => 'else',
        'title' => 'demo',
        'content' => 'stack_overflow',
        'year' => 2020,
    )
);
```

Уникальным ключом является `title`, выходит массивы с индексами `0, 1`, являются дублями, таких массивов может быть очень много...

Мне нужно оставить только тот массив в котором меньше всего значений `null`, то есть в данном случае массив с индексом `1` нужно удалить, так-как это дубль массива с индексом `0` и т.д. Таких дублей может быть разное количество.

Думал сделать что-то подобное:

```
if(strlen(serialize($array))) {
    //Пишем массив который длиннее 
}
```

Но не могу придумать как найти совпадения...

Comment: Перебирайте форычем и проверяйте текущий уникальный ключ и количество null-ов.

Comment: @u_mulder, А можно Ваш пример?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В итоге написал такую функцию:

```
public function removeArrayDuplicates($array, $index_key) {
    $result = array_reverse(
        array_values(
            array_column(
                array_reverse($array), null, $index_key)
        )
    );

    return $result;
}

var_dump(removeArrayDuplicates($array, $title));
```

Получаю массивы без дублей и с нужными значениями.

**UPDATE: Всё таки не с нужными значениями.**

Данная функция не сработала как ожидалось поэтому нагородил другую. Эта точно работает как нужно. Может кому то будет полезно, либо сможете улучшить мой ответ.

```
function removeArrayDuplicates($array, $search_key) {
    $stored_duplicates = array();
    $max_array_length = null;
    $current_array = null;
    $result = array();

    foreach($array as $item) {
        $stored_duplicates[$item[$search_key]][] = $item;
    }

    foreach($stored_duplicates as $arrays) {
        foreach($arrays as $item) {
            if(count($arrays) > 1) {
                $array_length = strlen(serialize($item));

                if($array_length > $max_array_length) {
                    $max_array_length = $array_length;
                    $current_array = $item;
                }
            }

            else {
                $result[] = $item;
            }
        }

        if($current_array) {
            $result[] = $current_array;

            $max_array_length = null;
            $current_array = null;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```